# how to add another column in another spinner of same or other table in android studio

Tags: java, android, string, android-sqlite

how to add second column value of same or other table in another spinner from sqlite  database using button click in android studio

```
    retrievebtn.setOnClickListener(arg0 -> {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nos.clear();
        names.clear();

        //OPEN
        db.openDB();

           //RETRIEVE
           Cursor c = db.getAllValues();

        c.moveToFirst();
        while(!c.isAfterLast())
        {
            String no = c.getString(0);
            nos.add(no);
            String name = c.getString(1);
            names.add(name);
            c.moveToNext();
        }

               //CLOSE
               c.close();
               db.close();

               //SET IT TO SPINNER
               sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
               sp2.setAdapter(adapter);


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My adapters were not set so I made below changes and got expected result.

```
// RETRIEVE
retrievebtn.setOnClickListener(arg0 -> {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nos.clear();
        names.clear();

        //OPEN
        db.openDB();

           //RETRIEVE
           Cursor c = db.getAllValues();

        c.moveToFirst();
        while(!c.isAfterLast())
        {
            String no = c.getString(0);
            nos.add(no);

            String name = c.getString(1);
            names.add(name);
            c.moveToNext();
        }

               //CLOSE
               c.close();
               db.close();

               //SET IT TO SPINNER
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nos);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

        sp1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider the following working example.

This consists of 2 spinners and 3 buttons. The buttons controlling from which of the 3 tables the data is extracted for the 2nd spinner.

The trick, as such, used is to use AS to utilise a standard column name, irrespective of the actual column name. The one difference is that this rather than using a normal adapter, it utilises a CursorAdapter (SimpleCursorAdapter as it's quite flexible) and thus you can extract the data directly.

First the SQLite side i.e. the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper :-

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db";
   public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   public static final String TABLE1_TABLE = "_table1";
   public static final String TABLE1_ID_COL = BaseColumns._ID;
   public static final String TABLE1_NAME_COL = "_name";
   public static final String TABLE1_DESC_COL = "_desc";
   private static final String TABLE1_CREATE_SQL =
           "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE1_TABLE + "(" +
                   TABLE1_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                   "," + TABLE1_NAME_COL + " TEXT UNIQUE" +
                   "," + TABLE1_DESC_COL + " TEXT " +
                   ");";

   public static final String TABLE2_TABLE = "_table2";
   public static final String TABLE2_ID_COL = BaseColumns._ID;
   public static final String TABLE2_TABLE1_ID_MAP_COL = "_table1_id_map";
   public static final String TABLE2_NAME_COL = "_name";
   private static final String TABLE2_CREATE_SQL =
           "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE2_TABLE + "(" +
                   TABLE2_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                   "," + TABLE2_TABLE1_ID_MAP_COL + " INTEGER " +
                   "," + TABLE2_NAME_COL + " TEXT" +
                   ");";

   public static final String TABLE3_TABLE = "_table3";
   public static final String TABLE3_ID_COL = BaseColumns._ID;
   public static final String TABLE3_TABLE2_ID_MAP_COL = "_table2_id_map";
   public static final String TABLE3_NAME_COL = "_name";
   private static final String TABLE3_CREATE_SQL =
           "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE3_TABLE +"(" +
                   TABLE3_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                   "," + TABLE3_TABLE2_ID_MAP_COL + " INTEGER " +
                   "," + TABLE3_NAME_COL + " TEXT " +
                   ");";

   private static volatile DBHelper INSTANCE;
   private SQLiteDatabase db;
   public static final String SPINNER_COLUMN1 = "_spc1";
   public static final String SPINNER_COLUMN2 = "_spc2";

   private DBHelper(Context context) {
      super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
      db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
      if (INSTANCE==null) {
         INSTANCE = new DBHelper(context);
      }
      return INSTANCE;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(TABLE1_CREATE_SQL);
      db.execSQL(TABLE2_CREATE_SQL);
      db.execSQL(TABLE3_CREATE_SQL);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

   }

   public long insertTable1Row(String name,String description) {
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put(TABLE1_NAME_COL,name);
      cv.put(TABLE1_DESC_COL,description);
      return db.insert(TABLE1_TABLE,null,cv);
   }
   public long insertTable2Row(String name, long table1_id) {
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put(TABLE2_NAME_COL,name);
      cv.put(TABLE2_TABLE1_ID_MAP_COL,table1_id);
      return db.insert(TABLE2_TABLE,null,cv);
   }

   public long insertTable3Row(String name, long table2_id) {
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put(TABLE3_NAME_COL,name);
      cv.put(TABLE3_TABLE2_ID_MAP_COL,table2_id);
      return db.insert(TABLE3_TABLE,null,cv);
   }

   public Cursor getSpinnerData(String table, long map) {

      String[] columns = new String[]{};
      String whereClause = "";
      String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(map)};
      switch (table) {
         case TABLE1_TABLE:
            columns = new String[]{TABLE1_ID_COL,TABLE1_NAME_COL + " AS " + SPINNER_COLUMN1,TABLE1_DESC_COL + " AS " + SPINNER_COLUMN2};
            whereClause = "";
            break;
         case TABLE2_TABLE:
            columns = new String[]{TABLE2_ID_COL ,TABLE2_NAME_COL + " AS " + SPINNER_COLUMN1,"'-' AS " + SPINNER_COLUMN2};
            whereClause = TABLE2_TABLE1_ID_MAP_COL + "=?";
            break;
         case TABLE3_TABLE:
            columns = new String[]{TABLE3_ID_COL, TABLE3_NAME_COL + " AS " + SPINNER_COLUMN1,"'~' AS " + SPINNER_COLUMN2};
            whereClause = TABLE3_TABLE2_ID_MAP_COL + "=?";
            break;
      }
      if (map < 0) {
         whereClause="";
         whereArgs = new String[]{};
      }
      if (columns.length > 0) {
         return db.query(table,columns,whereClause,whereArgs,null,null,null);
      } else {
         return db.query(TABLE1_TABLE,new String[]{"0 AS " + TABLE1_ID_COL + ",'ooops' AS " + SPINNER_COLUMN1,"'ooops' AS " + SPINNER_COLUMN2},null,null,null,null,null,"1");
      }
   }
}
```

- as said there are three tables
- a singleton approach has been utilised for the DBHelper
- the most relevant aspect in regards to switching spinner data is the `getSpinnerData` function, which takes two parameters, the most relevant being the first the tablename which drives the resultant query.
- Note the use of **BaseColumns._ID** **ALL** Cursor adapters must have a column name **_id** (which is what BaseColumns._ID resolves to). The column should be an integer value that uniquely identifies the row.
- the 2nd parameter caters for the selection of only related data, but a negative is used to ignore this aspect.

The Activity "MainActivity" used to demonstrate is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
    Spinner sp1,sp2;
    String[] spinnerColumns = new String[]{DBHelper.SPINNER_COLUMN1,DBHelper.SPINNER_COLUMN2};
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca1,sca2;
    String sp1_table_name = DBHelper.TABLE1_TABLE;
    String sp2_table_name = DBHelper.TABLE2_TABLE;
    Cursor csr1, csr2;
    DBHelper dbHelper;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1 = this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn3 = this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        sp1 = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp2 = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(this);
        Cursor test4Data = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(DBHelper.TABLE1_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null, "1");
        if (test4Data.getCount() < 1) {
            addSomeData();
        }
        test4Data.close();
        sp1_table_name = DBHelper.TABLE1_TABLE;
        sp2_table_name = DBHelper.TABLE2_TABLE;
        setUpButtons();
        setOrRefreshSpinner1();
        setOrRefreshSpinner2();
    }

    void setUpButtons() {
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sp2_table_name = DBHelper.TABLE1_TABLE;
                setOrRefreshSpinner2();
                setOrRefreshSpinner1();
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sp2_table_name = DBHelper.TABLE2_TABLE;
                setOrRefreshSpinner2();
                setOrRefreshSpinner1();
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sp2_table_name = DBHelper.TABLE3_TABLE;
                setOrRefreshSpinner2();
                setOrRefreshSpinner1();
            }
        });
    }

    void setOrRefreshSpinner1() {
        csr1 = dbHelper.getSpinnerData(sp1_table_name,-1);
        if (sca1==null) {
            sca1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    csr1,
                    spinnerColumns,
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},0
            );
            sp1.setAdapter(sca1);
        } else {
            sca1.swapCursor(csr1);
        }
    }
     void setOrRefreshSpinner2() {
        csr2 = dbHelper.getSpinnerData(sp2_table_name,-1);
        if (sca2==null) {
            sca2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    csr2,
                    spinnerColumns,
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},0
            );
            sp2.setAdapter(sca2);
        } else {
            sca2.swapCursor(csr2);
        }
     }

     private void addSomeData() {
        long n1 = dbHelper.insertTable1Row("NAME001","The first name.");
        long n2 = dbHelper.insertTable1Row("NAME002","The second name.");
        long n3 = dbHelper.insertTable1Row("NAME003","The third name");
        long t2n1 = dbHelper.insertTable2Row("CHILDNAME001",n1);
        long t2n2 = dbHelper.insertTable2Row("CHILDNAME002",n2);
        long t2n3 = dbHelper.insertTable2Row("CHILDNAME003", n3);
        dbHelper.insertTable3Row("GRANDCHILDNAME001",t2n1);
        dbHelper.insertTable3Row("GRANDCHILDNAME002",t2n1);
        dbHelper.insertTable3Row("GRANDCHILDNAME003",t2n1);
        dbHelper.insertTable3Row("GRANDCHILDNAME004",t2n2);
        dbHelper.insertTable3Row("GRANDCHILDNAME005",t2n3);
     }
}
```

**Result**
The above when run starts of with :-
[image]

With the first spinner dropdown shown :-

[image]

With the second spinner dropdown shown :-
[image]

If Button1 is clicked then both spinners (i.e. spinner2 has been changed to select data from Table1 rather than Table2) show data from Table1 (useless but for demonstration) :-

[image]

If Button3 is clicked then data from Table3 is displayed in the second spinner:-

[image]

Clicking Button2 shows data from Table2.

Of course the principle could be applied in many different ways.